# MySQL - Match certain IDs, but only those IDs

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like so:

```
id_type         id_option
"1"         "1"
"1"         "5"
"2"         "1"
"2"         "5"
"2"         "8"
```

I am trying to write a query that given a list of option IDs finds the "type" that matches the list, but only those ID's

For example, if given 1 and 5 as options, it should return the type 1 but only the type 1 as the 8 required to match type 2 is not present.

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE id_option IN (1, 5)
GROUP BY id_type
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id_option) = 2
```

This returns both "types" - I had hoped that the COUNT restriction of 2 would have helped but I now understand why it doesn't, but I can't think of a clever way to limit this.

I could just pull the first record as typically the types with less options are saved first but I don't think I can rely on this 100%

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
GROUP BY id_type
HAVING SUM(id_option IN (1,5)) = COUNT(*)
```

It relies on a trick specific to MySQL: boolean `true` is literally the integer 1. So you can use SUM() to count the rows where a condition is true, but putting a boolean expression inside SUM().

For folks reading this who use other databases besides MySQL, you'd have to use an expression to convert the boolean condition to the integer 1:

```
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN id_option IN (1,5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(*)
```

In this case, let all rows become part of the groups. That is, do not use a WHERE clause to restrict the query to rows where the id_option is 1 or 5. Then count the total rows in the group, and "count" (i.e. use the SUM() trick) the rows where the id_options is 1 or 5. Comparing these counts will be equal if there are no id_options values besides 1 or 5.

If you also want to make sure that *both* 1 and 5 are found, you need another condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
GROUP BY id_type
HAVING SUM(id_option IN (1,5)) = COUNT(*)
  AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN id_option IN (1,5) THEN id_option END) = 2
```

The CASE expression will return 1 or 5, or if there are any other values, those are converted to NULL. The COUNT() function ignores NULLs.

Comment: Thank you very much - great explanation and solid solution

Answer (score 3):

If you can pass the options as a sorted comma separated list string, then use `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT id_type
FROM my_table
GROUP BY id_type
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(id_option ORDER BY id_option) = '1,5'
```

If there are duplicate options for each type, use `DISTINCT`:

```
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id_option ORDER BY id_option) = '1,5'
```

Comment: Perfect! - thank you very much, I will mark as answered now.

Comment: Hi @forpas - I was a little hasty to mark as answered, I feel the answer above is a little more "complete" so have amended, I have +1'd you though!

Answer (score 0):

While I can't comment yet, here's a tiny adjustment to Bill Karwin's last example (in the accepted solution):

```
SELECT *
  FROM my_table
 GROUP BY id_type
HAVING SUM(id_option IN (1,5)) = COUNT(*)
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT id_option) = 2
```

Comment: Note also that a unique constraint on (id_type, id_option) and NOT NULL constraint on id_option would remove the need for that logic.  Leading to just: HAVING SUM(id_option IN (1,5)) = COUNT(*).  Nothing more is needed.